# jQuery cannot remove attribute from drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I cannot remove the option selected what am I doing wrong?

This is done in the console

```
[
<select class=​"engclass">​…​</select>​
]
$(".engclass").removeAttr('selected').val("Application # 1").attr('selected',true);
[
<select class=​"engclass" selected=​"selected">​
<option value=​"-1" selected>​Choose application​</option>​
<option value=​"1">​Application # 1​</option>​
<option value=​"2">​Application # 2​</option>​
<option value=​"3">​Application # 3​</option>​
</select>​
```

Comment: Why do you have selected on the 'select'?

Comment: beacuse thats by default

Comment: Is `.val("Application # 1")` supposed to be setting the value, or should it be selecting the option with that text?

Comment: Are you trying to actually remove the `<option>` tag of whichever option is selected?

Comment: Yes i am trying to remove what is set by default

Comment: Are yo sure you can have 'selected="selected"' on a <select />. I thought it was only meant for <option /> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$(".engclass").removeAttr('selected')
                    .find(":contains('Application # 1')")
                    .prop('selected',true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U73Ru/

Answer (score 2):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()`:

Also, you must use it on the `<option>`s not the `<select>` itself.. [wroking jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veV7r/)

```
$(".engagement_app option:first-child").prop('selected',true); // select first
$(".engagement_app option:first-child").prop('selected',false); // deselect first
```

Comment: $(".engagement_app").prop('selected',false).val("Application # 1").prop('selected',true); still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the `selected` attribute from a `select` as it **must** always have 1 selected option. Instead, you simply set the `val` to the element you'd like to select. Try this:

```
$(".engagement_app").val("1"); // should select​ Application # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$(".engagement_app option").removeAttr('selected');
$(".engagement_app option[value="1"]").attr('selected',true);
```